# Return result of the expression or variable

Tags: php

I read the documentation and it says the following:

> ***Note:*** You should never use parentheses around your return variable
>   when returning by reference, as this will not work. You can only
>   return variables by reference, not the result of a statement. If you
>   use return ($a); then you're not returning a variable, but the result
>   of the expression ($a) (which is, of course, the value of $a).

```
return ($a);
return $a;
```

What is the difference between the return of an expression or variable?

Comment: I guess, both of them, **are same**. :) Unless they are objects?

Comment: that is, there is no difference?

Comment: Please see the dupe for more information and clarity. Let me know if it doesn't solve.